# Allow a non-member to e-mail my Google Groups membership

Tags: email, google-groups

I am very new to Google Groups. I created a group and invited and joined my classmates as members. I want to know whether there is any possibility that I can give my Google Groups ID to my teacher (who is not a member of my group) so that he can send a mail to my Google Groups ID to reach all the membership?

Comment: That seems like it would be a TOS violation if it was possible.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the "Post Permission" to public.

Click the gear in upper right.  Then Group Settings in the dropdown.  Then on the left under the "Permissions" find "Basic Permissions" and set "Post" to public.  This allows anyone to send messages to the group via e-mail.

Comment: Now we have Roles. Could we somehow define a "Teacher" role to just post to the group, but not allow teachers to see anything from the group content?

Comment: I don't have this setting available in options. Are there reasons it might not be settable? Can it only be set by owner? Or do I have to enable it somewhere else? Or is it only for a certain paid tier? We have a custom domain and the group is owned by the domain and I am a moderator.

Comment: As of today, it's the "who can post" setting under: Group settings / general